# How do I add roles to existing user in MongoDB 2.4

Tags: mongodb

I've spent the obligatory hour trying to dig through MongoDB's online documentation, which is pretty shoddy for version 2.4, when user admin commands were in flux.

I've figured out that in mongoDB 2.4.11

```
db.addUser( { user: "...", pwd: "...", roles: [ ... ] } )
```

works. But I can't find any example of a command to update a user's roles, and I get this error message when I try to just overwrite the existing user:

```
 User already exists with that username/userSource combination at src/mongo/shell/db.js:125
```

So I'm stuck.

(and as bonus, how do I remove a role from an existing user in 2.4?)

When I try

```
db.grantRolesToUser( "myself", [  {role: "clusterAdmin"} ] )
```

as documented in v2.6, I get:

```
TypeError: Property 'grantRolesToUser' of object admin is not a function
```

so in 2.4 not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a clear documentation available in the mongodb website:

In v2.6 only:
To grant additional roles to the user, follow the steps given here: https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/assign-role-to-user/

To revoke a role for the user, follow this: https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/change-user-privileges/

For v2.4, try this from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23125827/1505987

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. But doesn't v2.6 in the URL mean it applies to 2.6 and not 2.4? The basic function addUser() changed to createUser() in 2.4-->2.6 so I'm not sure that it will work.

Comment: when I try to flip that page from 2.6 to 2.4 it redirects to some other page about user access with no mention of revoking roles

Comment: mongo shell replies: "TypeError: Property 'grantRolesToUser' of object admin is not a function"

Comment: @MarcMaxson: Updated the answer, kindly try and let me know.

Comment: I tried this: db.system.users.update({"myself" : "my password"}, {$addToSet: {roles: [ 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', 'readWriteAnyDatabase']}}) but nothing changed when I ran "show users" on admin.

Answer (score 7):

### 2021 Update

*MongoDB version* : 4.4.2

You can add roles to existing user with `db.grantRolesToUser()`

Official syntax : `db.grantRolesToUser( "<username>", [ <roles> ], { <writeConcern> } )`

With the following command, you can grant read & write access to all the databases except **local** & **config**

```bash
> use admin;
> db.grantRolesToUser('user1', ['readWriteAnyDatabase']);
```

However, if you would like to only grant read & write permission to a specific database like *account database* only, you can do it as below

```bash
use admin;
db.grantRolesToUser('user1', [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'account' }]);
```

MongoDB Ref : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/